# querySelectorAll with variable doesn't select the element

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables, nodelist, queryselector

I want to select all elements using querySelectorAll with variable "amountClass" but NodeList always is empty

```
    function addingCoin() {
const table = document.querySelector('.list__table');

table.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    
    const walletCryptos = document.querySelector('#usersCrypto');
    const coinAmount = event.target.inputAmount;
    const coinRow = coinAmount.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    const coinName = coinRow.querySelector('.name').textContent;
    const coinPrice = coinRow.querySelector('.price').textContent.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)[0];
    const coinValue = coinAmount.value*coinRow.querySelector('.price').textContent.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)[0];
    
    let amountClass = coinName;
    let existingCoin = document.querySelectorAll(amountClass);

    if (existingCoin.length > 0) {
        existingCoin[0].innerText = coinAmount.value + 
    existingCoin[0].value;

    } else {
    const newTr = document.createElement("tr");
    const nameTh = document.createElement("th");
    const priceTh = document.createElement("th");
    const amountTh = document.createElement("th");
    const valueTh = document.createElement("th");

    nameTh.innerText = coinName;

    if (coinPrice < 0.95) {
        priceTh.innerText = parseFloat(coinPrice).toFixed(8);
    } else {
        priceTh.innerText = parseFloat(coinPrice).toFixed(2);  
    };

    amountTh.innerText = coinAmount.value;
    
    amountTh.className += coinName;

    if (coinValue < 0.95) {
        valueTh.innerText = parseFloat(coinValue).toFixed(8);
    } else {
        valueTh.innerText = parseFloat(coinValue).toFixed(2);  
    };

    walletCryptos.appendChild(newTr);
    walletCryptos.appendChild(nameTh);
    walletCryptos.appendChild(priceTh);
    walletCryptos.appendChild(amountTh);
    walletCryptos.appendChild(valueTh);
    }});
    };
```

I think the problem may be with this part of code:

```
    let existingCoin = document.querySelectorAll(amountClass);
```

What can i change to make this work properly? Is there any other solution to check does the element with the certain class exist?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why not use `document.querySelectorAll(coinName)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: because in the future i will add some words to amountClass

Answer (score 1):

You need a `.` at the beginning to select a class.

Trim the text content in case it has whitespace around the text.

```
const coinName = coinRow.querySelector('.name').textContent.trim();
let amountClass = '.' + coinName
```

Comment: In console i have information this is not valid format, maybe because there is space between "." and coinName?

Comment: Use `trim()` to remove whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found the solution:

```
const amountClass = '.' + coinName;
    const existingCoin = document.querySelectorAll(amountClass.replace(/ /g,''));
```

Comment: Do you have spaces in the middle of the `coinName` value? If they're only at the end, my answer with `.trim()` should have worked.